# how to use ejs lint in cli

Tags: ejs, eslint

I am using EJS as my view engine on a node and express setup.  I want to use ejs-lint to help get the line for errors.  I haven't use a linter before, but from reading through the documentation here:  https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
I'm assuming you can just check errors on a specified file in command line like this: ejslint

Are my assumptions right and what am I doing wrong? I've already installed using `npm install ejs-lint --save-dev`

Also, if I plan to add ESlint to my project I'm guessing I can have it work alongside EJSlint?

Answer (score 6):

## Short answer

Run it directly from the terminal:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ejslint src/templates/some-template.ejs
```

Or with [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path):

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "lint:ejs": "ejslint src/templates/some-template.ejs"
  }
}

// terminal
npm run lint:ejs
```

ESLint and EJSlint are different, exclusive processes. What is analysed by ESLint should not be analysed by EJSLint and vice versa. Having both installed will not cause any issues.

## Extended answer

For what I have tested, you have to use the ejs linter CLI per file. Which is not as useful as `eslint` which can process multiple files, exclusions etc.

If you had some `src/templates` directory, you could lint all the EJS files by doing something like this:

```
find src/templates -type f -iname '*.ejs' -exec bash -c "./node_modules/.bin/ejslint '{}'" \;
```

Which would work for Unix but not for Windows. You could prepare some node script to do it cross system with the ejslint API.

There is also a [grunt plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ejslint) for it.

If you want to have both ESLint and EJSLint, you should have different npm scripts for them, e.g:

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:ejs",
    "lint:js": "eslint src --ignore-path src/templates",
    "lint:ejs": "find src/templates -type f -iname '*.ejs' -exec bash -c \"./node_modules/.bin/ejslint '{}'\" \\;"
  }
}
```

If you are using grunt, you can create different tasks for eslint and ejslint and then [create a group task](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask):

```
grunt.registerTask('lint', ['eslint', 'ejslint']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I tried both options for EJSLint and neither worked.  When I run this in my terminal it just hangs `./node_modules/.bin/ejslint src/templates/some-template.ejs`.  It is really frustrating that even the official documentation does not clearly explain how to use it.  Any other thoughts?  I should be catching something because I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in C:\dev\XXXX\views\eventdetail.ejs while compiling ejs
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint`

Comment: You might need to use it with Windows syntax rather than Unix: `.\node_modules\.bin\ejslint.cmd views\eventdetail.ejs`

Comment: The official EJS lint docs say that if you get such an error ("unexpected token") it might be due to a tag that's not closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `npx ejslint **/*.ejs` from the command-line in your project root to check all the ejs files in your project.

the `npx` is needed because you used `--save-dev` (or `-D`) if you used `--global` (or `-g`) then you can call ejs lint directly using `ejslint **/*.ejs`

`**/*.ejs` will select any file ending in `.ejs` in any folder.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the following way is the easiest and by far the fastest execution time. It also has better error logging because it doesn't pass through the find command.

```
ejslint $(find ./ -type f -iname '*.ejs')
```

Answer (score 0):

they is no definitve instructions on usage ejslint on cmd. try and debug your lines of code yourself with a debug in your editor ,as it says its something to do with syntax error within your code. worked for me.!

Ohh ya and good news is that you can still run ESlint aswell to debug your Js files .