# Where to find EJS-Lint output, and what should it look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I use EJS in my projects, and as it goes, I run into 500 errors every time some aspect of the EJS doesn't load properly--be it that a `res.locals` variable didn't get passed in, or a file path is wrong in a `render()` method.

All I receive is a 500 error. No messages, no line numbers, no error type, nothing.

Here is the terminal output when the page doesn't load:

[image]

And here's what the browser shows:

[image]

On other projects using a different kind of error display page, I've seen some error messages that say "If this isn't helpful, try EJS Lint", so I installed it and look into the "documentation", such as it is, and It has zero information about what to expect from output. I paste in the commands and the path to the file I need to test, and the CLI just sits there, and the API seems to do absolutely nothing.

Here's what I've tried in the CLI:

`ejslint /views/owner/dashboard.ejs`

And for the API call:

```js
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

ejsLint('../views/partials/addUserForm.ejs', {states, datePoints, beginDate, endDate, recentCompanies, allLocations, recentInvitations, recentForms,totalQuestions, totalCompanies, totalForms, graphDatasets, page:'ownerDashboard'});
```

Again, no messages. No errors. No output of any sort, at all.

Is there a resource somewhere that explains, step-by-step how to use this tool?

This answer is the closest I could find, and it still says nothing about where any output will show, what it will look like, how it will be formatted, etc: [how to use ejs lint in cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140310/how-to-use-ejs-lint-in-cli/48183883)

Comment: This is a very poor question sir, and I think you know it. Please leave out the hyperbole ("How on earth") and tell us specifically what your error messages are, and what you've tried to do to fix this

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Updated to use less emotional language due to frustration.

Comment: Thank you for taking my comment and fixing your question. I'm glad you took this in the spirit it was given in. Back to your problem: Are there no logs? A 500 level exception means a server error. I don't understand how using lint would be useful. And that can't be how the creators of ejs imagined people would debug, or? Without the actual error message and the file/line its at, oi...